# Что выбрать после изучения MYSQL?

Tags: access, база-данных

Привет. Сначала изучил MYSQL. Выбрал его, потому что он тесно связан с вебом. Хочу углубиться в изучении БД. Подскажите, что сейчас востребованно?

Microsoft SQL Server, Oracle, MS Access или что-то другое... Если честно, я не знаю толком их назначения. Критерий востребованности здесь главный. Если можно простенькую аннотацию для выбора. Благодарен.

Comment: "изучил" это как?
За 2-5 месяцев по 1-2 книгам?

Answer (score 3):

Учи oracle, за него зарплаты хорошие.

Если ты изучил mysql, подскажи, пожалуйста, как там создать триггер и при этом определить максимальное количество памяти, которое он может использовать, чтобы вся база не рухнула. И как можно запретить триггеру вносить изменения в базу при его запуске?

**Обновление**

Читать про создание триггеров в mysql здесь http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/trigger-syntax.html
Про память и запреты мне самому интересно. "Я не настоящий сварщик". Чел же сказал, что выучил mysql, я думал он знает.

Я думаю, при запуске триггеров используются общие ограничения по памяти из настроек mysql. Было бы странно давать триггеру больше памяти, чем это разрешено всей БД, но и меньше давать бессмысленно.  А запреты, наверное, реализуются отменой транзакций по окончании работы триггера или банальным IF в начале триггера.

Прокачиваться стоит на работе, побольше практики.

Comment: ну так как? Поделитесь секретом ) У меня с триггерами как-то вообще слабоватенько будет

Comment: @Get, потом поделишься секретом? Ну или ссылками на литературу,, где до такого уровня можно прокачаться?

Comment: Обновил ответ

Comment: Чьерт) Я думал тут что-то хитрое.